# Page Doesn't Refresh after AJAX is successful

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My page doesn't refresh when there are no errors.

I used:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

That is *supposed* to be executed when `data.success` returns True.

I'm new to PHP and AJAX, so I'm using [this](https://github.com/scotch-io/ajax-forms-jquery/blob/master/magic.js) as a guide.  I know how to process info to server, but I want to display messages without leaving the page.

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// connects to "ajax" database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
mysql_select_db("ajax");


// assigns variables to fields
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$superheroAlias = $_POST['superheroAlias'];


$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['email']))
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['superheroAlias']))
        $errors['superheroAlias'] = 'Superhero alias is required.';

// return a response ===========================================================

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO inputs SET name = '$name', email = '$email', alias = '$superheroAlias'";

        $query = @mysql_query($sql);

        header("location: /");

    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**JS**

```
// magic.js
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
    $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'superheroAlias'    : $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true,
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            if (!data.success) {

                // handle errors for name ---------------
                if (data.errors.name) {
                    $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

                // handle errors for email ---------------
                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

                // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                if (data.errors.superheroAlias) {
                    $('#superhero-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                    $('#superhero-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.superheroAlias + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                }

            } else {

                    window.location.reload(true);

            }
        })

        // using the fail promise callback
        .fail(function(data) {

            // show any errors
            // best to remove for production
            console.log(data);
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Comment: Can use a breakpoint in the ``anonymous function`` passed to the ``done`` function and see if the control is going there?

Comment: what do you get if you do a `console.log(data)` above `window.location.reload(true);`

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your code. To begin with, the reason your AJAX call is only executed when there are errors is because you're relocating your page when there aren't any errors.

```
header("location: /");
```

Is your culprit. You're relocating the page before you can ever output any JSON. Second of all, your `$data` variable doesn't contain the `[success]` key when there is a successful $_POST transit. So even if you *weren't* to relocate, you still wouldn't be outputting any useful data. *Third* of all, you never saved a link to your MySQL database, you only instantiated it. Also, you're going to want to use `mysqli_` because `mysql_` is deprecated.

Change those first two lines of code to this:

```
$link = new mysqli( "localhost", "root", "password", "ajax" );
```

Change that `if-statement` to this:

```
if ( ! empty( $errors ) ) {
    $data["errors"] = $errors;
    $data["success"] = false;
} else {
    $data["success"] = true;
    $data["errors"] = $errors; // There are none, so this isn't neccessary

    $sql = "INSERT INTO inputs SET name = '$name', email = '$email', alias = '$superheroAlias'";
    $link->query( $sql );
}
```

By the way, I hope this is for demonstration purposes only, because that is some terrible validation/sanitation. If it isn't, here are some useful links:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html -- In-depth tutorial on sanitation/validation
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php -- Your guide to the MySQLi library.

Comment: This doesn't work, nor does removing the header location.  I don't know what the problem is.  I'm a front-end dev, not back-end.

Comment: @Matthew Do you get any errors of some sort? Those are really helpful when debugging.

Comment: It doesn't send anything. :P

Comment: I'll continue to play around with it

Comment: Alright good luck man. Thought i could be of help. Check your browser's console for JS errors and make sure PHP is in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

remove `header("location: /");` from your php file in else part.
I think this will redirect page so, your response is not like you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here If condition fails then check for $data in else and remove header from else.



     if ( ! empty($errors)) {

                // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
                $data['success'] = false;
                $data['errors']  = $errors;
            } else {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO inputs SET name = '$name', email = '$email', alias = '$superheroAlias'";

                $query = @mysql_query($sql);
                $data['success'] = false;
                //header("location: /");

            }

            // return all our data to an AJAX call
            echo json_encode($data);
```